# Passing arguments from managed C# to Managed C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

what is the preferred method to pass a string between C++ and C#?
i have a c++ class where one of the functions takes a `const char var1 and const char var2[]` as parameter.

When I call such function in C# , function accepts arguments types as sbyte*.
Just using a c#-string doesnt seem to work as the function in C# requires a sbyte* and sbyte**

C++ class:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    void Sample(const char * var1,const char* Var2[]);
}
```

C# call...

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
               MyClass oClass = new MyClass();
               string var1 = "Variable1";
               string[] var2 = {"1","2"};
               oClass.Sample(var1,var2);
        }
}
```

Error:
Error 1 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'sbyte*'
Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'sbyte**'

So I need help in understanding how can I pass string arguments from managed C# to managed C++?

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure you'd just pass the `System.String`.  (`String^` in C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A char * [] is not the same as a C# string.  In the managed C++, you want a String^, like this

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    void Sample(String^ var1, array<String^>^ var2);
};
```

Comment: Please pay a bit of attention to your code snippets, they'll get lots of SO users in trouble with basic syntax mistakes.